# How to select count of a table using ServiceStack OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

How can I select the count from a table and include a `where` clause to return a `long`?  Ideally I would use `db.Count` instead of `db.Select`.  I'm just not sure how to use `db.Count` and cannot find documentation on it.

```cs
long totalCount = 0;
using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    totalCount = db.Count<Content>( ?? );
}
Console.WriteLine(totalCount);
```

Comment: A lambda appears to have worked in this case.  It didn't seem to want to add first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You answered for you question in your comment ;) You should use Count extension method with expression parameter. Example below:

```
long amout  = db.Count<Post>(x => x.Subject == "test");
```

OrmLite generates following sql:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM POST WHERE (SUBJECT = 'test')
```

Comment: Exactly what I found.  Thank Adam.